# Facebook USER access token used instead of APP access token for public resources

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

Apparently (for my Facebook app) any valid USER access token works when used as an APP access token (normally acquired like this https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1} for accessing public resources  that do not require user permissions, like news feeds). Are there any issues related to such an usage (besides the obvious that the USER access token must be valid, not expired)?

Answer (score 1):

You can run into a user limit on the token, that's the only thing I can think of